# What joseki, if any, yields this position on page 60 of 38 Basic Joseki?

Tags: go, joseki

When introducing pincer [joseki](/questions/tagged/joseki) on page 60 of *38 Basic Joseki*, Kiyoshi Kosugi and James Davies use this position as an illustration:

```
$$Bc Illustration of pincer
$$ ---------
$$ ........-
$$ .....O..-
$$ ..X.OX..-
$$ ..O.OX..-
$$ ...OX...-
$$ ...OX...-
$$ ...XX...-
$$ ........-
$$ ........-
$$ ....,...-
$$ ........-
$$ .....1..-
$$ ........-
$$ ........-
$$ .....O..-
$$ ....,...-
$$ ....X...-
$$ ........-
$$ ........-
$$ ---------
```

I have tried without success to find this joseki/position with pattern search on [Sensei’ s Library](https://senseis.xmp.net/?positionsearch=1) and [Eidogo](http://eidogo.com/#search) and by experimentation on [Josekipedia](http://www.josekipedia.com/). I also could not find it in *38 Basic Joseki*, nor in Ishida’s *Dictionary of Basic Joseki*, though perhaps I erroneously skipped some positions that seemed to me to be excluded.

Does this position arise from a recognised joseki? If so, which, and how might I have been able to find it on-line or in a book?

Since Black has seven stones to White’s six, he must have started (probably 3-3, 3-4 or 4-5) or White must have played tenuki, but I cannot find a very plausible order.

#### Update: partial match

While [mafu](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/60/mafu) correctly remarked that it looked like a *hoshi approached from both sides, low and high, with black then jumping into the corner after white attached on top of the high approaching stone*, I found [the following partial position](http://www.josekipedia.com/#path:qdndnepcpdodoeqcmd) in Josekipedia:

```
$$Wc Partial sequence
$$ ---------
$$ ........-
$$ ........-
$$ ....18..-
$$ ....54..-
$$ ...76...-
$$ ...32...-
$$ ....a...-
$$ ........-
```

which it attributes to *[Encyclopedia of Joseki](https://senseis.xmp.net/?GendaiJosekiJiten) - Diagram 2.9365*. White 3 is a trick move, this is the refutation, but it continues at **a** (reverting to a standard 1-point high joseki), so this is not the answer.

Comment: Looks like a hoshi that was approached from both sides, low and high, with black then jumping into the corner after white attached on top of the  high approaching stone. I don't know the joseki sequence, but the result seems like a perfect fit for this.

Comment: @Mafu: You are right; it is _38 Basic Joseki, p 188, Dia. 4_ — not sure how I missed it :(. If you do not care to provide this as an answer, I shall do it myself.

Comment: Please feel free to put up the answer! I was just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The joseki

This is, as [mafu](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/60/mafu) pointed out, the result of a joseki starting with high and low near kakaris against a hoshi, shown in  *38 Basic Joseki, page 188, Dia. 4* (with colours swapped and rotated to match the question), and [in Josekipedia](http://www.josekipedia.com/#path:pdqfttndnemeoeqcqdpcrcodpfmd):

```
$$Wc Double kakari joseki
$$ -----------
$$ ..........-
$$ ......c7b.-
$$ a...X.54..-
$$ O...9.O6..-
$$ d....38...-
$$ .....1X...-
$$ .....20...-
$$ ..........-
```

N.B. The pincer is not visible in the diagram mentioned in the question.

The position is also shown in Ishida’s *Dictionary of Basic Joseki, Vol II, p. 186, Dia. 96*, but with the White pincer (Black in Ishida as the colours are reversed) at **a**; in this case, after White **9**, Black exchanges **b** for White **c** before connecting at **10**, and finally White plays at **d**.

This joseki appeared not to be in Senseis Library, though it belonged on the page [4-4 point, low-high double approach, hane](https://senseis.xmp.net/?44PointLowHighDoubleApproachHane); I have since added it there. [Eidogo](http://eidogo.com/#kjd) appears to contain only double high and double low kakaris against hoshi, but not the high/low variant.

#### How to find it

***To be worked out***

> I tried without success to find this joseki/position with pattern search on [Sensei’ s Library](https://senseis.xmp.net/?positionsearch=1) and [Eidogo](http://eidogo.com/#search). That was reasonable, as it appears not to have been in either source, though I have since added it to Sensei and it is now found. I also failed to find it in *38 Basic Joseki*, and in Ishida’s *Dictionary of Basic Joseki*; that was mainly due to not guessing correctly how the joseki started.  I also failed to find it by experimentation on [Josekipedia](http://www.josekipedia.com/), again through not trying guessing the start. ***To add**: suggestions for more effective searching*.
>
> Since Black has seven stones to White’s six, he must have started (probably 3-3, 3-4 or 4-5) or White must have started and then played tenuki.